# How to show fedex estimated delivery date to be displayed along with the shipping option on my checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, date, fedex, delivery

Currently in checkout process, in shipping method section Fedex Shipping method showing as  -

Federal Express

```
Ground - $13.86
Standard Overnight - $36.87
2 Day - $36.87
```

I would like the estimated delivery date to be displayed along with the shipping option on my checkout page.

Federal Express

```
Ground - Est. Delivery February 21, 2016 $13.86
Standard Overnight - Est. Delivery February 21, 2016 $36.87
2 Day - Est. Delivery February 21, 2016 $36.87
```

One more thing "Is Fedex return delivery date ?" if yes "how can i get the delivery date ?".

Comment: Kindly refer to this SO link:-
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020756/magento-display-no-of-day-needed-for-fedex-shipping-methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020756/magento-display-no-of-day-needed-for-fedex-shipping-methods)

Comment: Its hard coded, I want to show delivery date that comes from Fedex.

Comment: Hope this helps. Checkout this link! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513269/fedex-rate-api-request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513269/fedex-rate-api-request)

Comment: no its not helping, might be something magento handling from wsdl files over here - app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/wsdl/FedEx

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Fedex returns delivery date but you have to configure the request sent to the api accordingly.

I am not sure your version of magento, This will work in Magento 1.9.x.

1. Rewrite "Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex" method "_formRateRequest"
2. add 'ReturnTransitAndCommit'=>true to the "ratesRequest" array,

   ```
   ...
   $ratesRequest = array(
       'ReturnTransitAndCommit'=>true,
   ....
   ```

   Now if you log the response in "_prepareRateResponse", you will see something similar to

   ```
   [RateReplyDetails] => Array
   (
       [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [ServiceType] => FIRST_OVERNIGHT
               [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
               [DeliveryStation] => KCKA 
               [DeliveryDayOfWeek] => FRI
               [DeliveryTimestamp] => 2016-02-19T08:00:00
               [CommitDetails] => stdClass Object
                   (
                       [ServiceType] => FIRST_OVERNIGHT
                       [CommitTimestamp] => 2016-02-19T08:00:00
                       [DayOfWeek] => FRI
                       [DestinationServiceArea] => A1
                       [BrokerToDestinationDays] => 0
                       [DocumentContent] => NON_DOCUMENTS
                   )

               [DestinationAirportId] => MCI
            ....
   ```

Notice

```
                [DeliveryDayOfWeek] => FRI
                [DeliveryTimestamp] => 2016-02-19T08:00:00
```

To get the timestamp to the checkout page, override "_prepareRateResponse" method by the following code (change is marked as - checkpoint)

```
protected function _prepareRateResponse($response)
{
    $costArr = array();
    $priceArr = array();
    $errorTitle = 'Unable to retrieve tracking';

    if (is_object($response)) {
        if ($response->HighestSeverity == 'FAILURE' || $response->HighestSeverity == 'ERROR') {
            if (is_array($response->Notifications)) {
                $notification = array_pop($response->Notifications);
                $errorTitle = (string)$notification->Message;
            } else {
                $errorTitle = (string)$response->Notifications->Message;
            }
        } elseif (isset($response->RateReplyDetails)) {
            $allowedMethods = explode(",", $this->getConfigData('allowed_methods'));

            if (is_array($response->RateReplyDetails)) {
                foreach ($response->RateReplyDetails as $rate) {
                    $serviceName = (string)$rate->ServiceType;
                    if (in_array($serviceName, $allowedMethods)) {
                        $amount = $this->_getRateAmountOriginBased($rate);
                        $costArr[$serviceName]  = $amount;
                        $priceArr[$serviceName] = $this->getMethodPrice($amount, $serviceName);
                        $timestamp[$serviceName] = (string) $rate->DeliveryTimestamp;//checkpoint
                    }
                }
                asort($priceArr);
            } else {
                $rate = $response->RateReplyDetails;
                $serviceName = (string)$rate->ServiceType;
                if (in_array($serviceName, $allowedMethods)) {
                    $amount = $this->_getRateAmountOriginBased($rate);
                    $costArr[$serviceName]  = $amount;
                    $priceArr[$serviceName] = $this->getMethodPrice($amount, $serviceName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    if (empty($priceArr)) {
        $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $error->setErrorMessage($errorTitle);
        $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
        $result->append($error);
    } else {
        foreach ($priceArr as $method=>$price) {
            $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
            $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $rate->setMethod($method);
            $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getCode('method', $method));
            $rate->setCost($costArr[$method]);
            $rate->setPrice($price);
            $rate->setDeliveryTimeStamp($timestamp[$method]);//checkpoint
            $result->append($rate);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Rewrite "Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Rate" as

```
 public function  importShippingRate(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Abstract $rate)
{
    $rateData = parent::importShippingRate($rate);
    if ($rate instanceof Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method) {
          $rateData->setDeliveryTimeStamp($rate->getDeliveryTimeStamp());
    }
    return $rateData;
}
```

Go to desing/frontend/[package]/[theme]/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml and call the time stamp as

```
         ...
        foreach ($_rates as $_rate): 
          ...
         echo  $_rate->getDeliveryTimeStamp();
          ....
      endforeach;
```

You can format the  the timestamp using php methods.

I hope this helps!

Comment: For Magento Enterprise and/or newer versions of Magento, you'll want this instead:
`public function importShippingRate(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Abstract $rate)
{
 parent::importShippingRate($rate);

 if ($rate instanceof Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method) {
  $this->setDeliveryTimeStamp($rate->getDeliveryTimeStamp());
 }

 return $this;
}`